# Reading struct from a binary file results in wrong characters

Tags: c, struct, binaryfiles

I have a program that writes `struct` to a binary file and then reads it, but the entered data does not match with output data, after reading it, there are wrong characters.

This is what I expected after entering data:

```
|First Name          | Last Name           | Location           | ID          |
--------------------------------------------------------------
John                   Doe                   London               1
```

This is what I got:

```
|First Name          | Last Name           | Location           | ID          |
--------------------------------------------------------------
└$↔                 | îQ@                 | á¡ K∙⌂    | 1385584
```

How can this be fixed, so that the output is formatted in readable characters?
I tried changing the struct element sizes but after increasing after 16 and reducing below 15, i got additional read errors.

The program looks like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wwrite-strings"
struct user{
    char firstname[16], lastname[16], location[16];
    unsigned int id;};

struct user * data_entry(){
    struct user *data = (struct user*) malloc(sizeof(struct user));
    printf("Enter first name:");
    scanf("%s", data->firstname);
    printf("Enter last name:");
    scanf("%s", data->lastname);
    printf("Enter location:");
    scanf("%s", data->location);
    printf("Enter ID:");
    scanf("%d", &data->id);
    return data;}

int data_read(int bytes, int fd, const char *file){
    struct user *data = NULL;
    struct user *tmp;
    int idx = 0;
    int count = 0;
    data = (struct user *)malloc(sizeof(struct user));

    while (bytes > 0) {
      bytes = read(fd, data + count, sizeof(struct user));
      if (bytes == -1){
        printf("File read error: %i (%s)\n",  errno, strerror(errno));
        close(fd);
        free(data);
        return errno;}

      if (!bytes){
        break;}

      if (bytes < sizeof(struct user)){
        printf("Error: read %i bytes out of %llu\n", bytes, sizeof(struct user));
        close(fd);
        free(data);
        return errno;}

        count++;
        tmp = (struct user *)realloc(data, sizeof(struct user) * (count + 1));

        if (!tmp){
          close(fd);
          free(data);
          return errno;}
        data = tmp;
  }
    printf("|First Name          |"
        " Last Name           |"
        " Location           |"
      " ID          |\n");
    printf("--------------------------------------------------------------\n");
    while (count--){
        printf("%-20s| %-20s| %-10s| %-7d\n",
                (data + idx)->firstname,
                (data + idx)->lastname,
                (data + idx)->location,
                &(data + idx)->id);
        idx++;}
    printf("\n[!] %i records from %s have been read\n", idx, file);
    printf("-------------------------------------------\n");
return 0;
}

int main (){
    int bytes = 1;
    int fd;
    int num;
    struct user *sp;
    const char *file = "data.bin";
    struct user *tmp;

    fd = open(file, O_CREAT | O_APPEND | O_RDWR, 0000777);

    if (fd == -1){
      printf("File open error: %i (%s)\n", errno, strerror(errno));
        return fd;}
    data_read(bytes, fd, file);

    sp = (struct user *)malloc(sizeof(struct user));
    if (!sp){
        printf("Memory allocation has failed\n");
        return -1;
    }
    sp = data_entry();
    bytes = write(fd, &sp, sizeof(struct user));
    if (bytes == -1) {
        printf("File write error: %i (%s)\n", errno, strerror(errno));
        close(fd);
        return bytes;}

    printf("User data saved to %u (%i bytes)\n", file, bytes);
    free(sp);
    close(fd);

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: There are several issues in your code. For example, data_entry allocate memory for data read and yet in main you still allocate memory. Write returns the number of bytes written, you should check that instead of -1. You call data_read before having written data. Do you expect the file contain data already? Don't forget that you must free all memory you have allocated or you'll get so called *memory leaks*.

Comment: You should turn on all compiler warnings and solve all warnings before continuing.

Comment: Did you mean to realloc by (count+1) when you had already count++?

Comment: Extract expressions from argument lists by adding more temp vars, print out values, use a debugger.  If you cannot debug, you cannot program.

Comment: @MartinJames Realloc(count+1) is OK. `count` is the number of already read structures.

Comment: your code is quite messy and a little strange for me. Your `data_read` do too many thing, and in a akward way. You have waa--aaay too many warning in your code, is this the real one you use ?

Comment: @fpiette. OP increments count, 'count++' then, immediately after, reallocs 'count+1').  That reallocs space for two items.

Comment: @MartinJames Yes, and he will read the next item in the reallocated space.

Comment: @fpiette, yes, i expect data to be read immediately, if there is no data, file is created and program asks for user input to enter it, if there is previous data, program immediately reads that data and shows in a table and then continues with asking user input to add more data.

Comment: @Tom's I'm using Atom with GCC, I'm seeing 7 warnings total, 2 are just of unused variables, 2 are unimportant notices about printf data types, the rest I just fixed with return 0 in data_read. But the main problem still persists.

Comment: You code is quite hard to read, please adapt a common code style and stick to it. As Martin said, learn to debug, single step through your program, watch the variables. If that sounds too much, add at least some `printf()` of interesting variables at several places to follow your program's logic. But after solving your issue, please learn to use a debugger.

Comment: Oh, and I remember the very same program some days ago. Is this a new account of yours, or did you delete the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fixed your code. The biggest error was when writing data to the file where you passed `&sp` while `sp`is already a pointer.

- I added some error checking.
- data_read do not close the file anymore (used later).
- Fixed all warnings (Compiled with MSVC2019).
- Used underscore prefixed function names for `open`, `read`, `write` and `close` (Remove underscore if your compiler doesn't like that).
- Freed allocated memory.

Thee is still plenty of room for improvement.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <io.h>           // MSVC2019 want that
//#include <unistd.h>     // MSVC2019 doesn't know it
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct user {
    char firstname[16], lastname[16], location[16];
    unsigned int id;
};

struct user* data_entry() {
    struct user* data = malloc(sizeof(struct user));
    if (data != NULL) {
        printf("Enter first name:");
        scanf("%s", data->firstname);
        printf("Enter last name:");
        scanf("%s", data->lastname);
        printf("Enter location:");
        scanf("%s", data->location);
        printf("Enter ID:");
        scanf("%d", &data->id);
    }
    return data;
}

int data_read(int fd, const char* fileName) {
    int bytes;
    struct user* data = NULL;
    struct user* tmp;
    int idx = 0;
    int count = 0;
    data = (struct user*)malloc(sizeof(struct user));
    if (data == NULL) {
        printf("Memory allocation error\n");
        return errno;
    }

    while (1) {
        bytes = _read(fd, data + count, sizeof(struct user));
        if (bytes == 0)  // End of file
            break;
        if (bytes == -1) {
            printf("File read error: %i (%s)\n", errno, strerror(errno));
            free(data);
            return errno;
        }

        if (bytes != sizeof(struct user)) {
            printf("Error: read %i bytes out of %d\n", bytes, sizeof(struct user));
            free(data);
            return errno;
        }

        count++;
        tmp = (struct user*)realloc(data, sizeof(struct user) * (count + 1));

        if (!tmp) {
            free(data);
            return errno;
        }
        data = tmp;
    }
    printf("|First Name          |"
        " Last Name           |"
        " Location           |"
        " ID          |\n");
    printf("--------------------------------------------------------------\n");
    while (count--) {
        printf("%-20s| %-20s| %-10s| %-7u\n",
            (data + idx)->firstname,
            (data + idx)->lastname,
            (data + idx)->location,
            (data + idx)->id);
        idx++;
    }
    printf("\n[!] %i records from %s have been read\n", idx, fileName);
    printf("-------------------------------------------\n");
    free(data);
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    int bytes;
    int fd;
    struct user* sp;
    const char* file = "data.bin";

    fd = _open(file, O_CREAT | O_APPEND | O_RDWR, 0000777);
    if (fd == -1) {
        printf("File open error: %i (%s)\n", errno, strerror(errno));
        return 1;
    }

    data_read(fd, file);

    sp = data_entry();
    if (sp == NULL) {
        printf("data_entry failed\n");
        _close(fd);
        return 1;
    }

    bytes = _write(fd, sp, sizeof(struct user));
    if (bytes != sizeof(struct user)) {
        if (bytes == -1)
            printf("File write error: %i (%s)\n", errno, strerror(errno));
        else
            printf("Not all bytes written to file\n");
        _close(fd);
        return 1;
    }

    printf("User data saved to %s (%i bytes)\n", file, bytes);
    free(sp);
    _close(fd);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I know I should not giving you code but here it is.
I rewrote a large part of your code because, like I said in the comment, I have the feeling that your function do too many thing at once.
I have also not take care of "chain-reading" many user struct from the fd, you can do it.

Basically, you have this struct :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wwrite-strings"

typedef struct user{
    char firstname[16];
    char lastname[16];
    char location[16];
    unsigned int id;
} user_s;
```

And I want to be able to do thing cleanly, so I wrote a constructor/destruction function to it (like open is the constructor of a fd, and close is his destructor)

```
#define USER_CONSTRUCTOR {.firstname[0] = '\0',  \
                          .lastname[0] = '\0',   \
                          .location[0] = '\0',   \
                          .id = 0                }

void User_Constructor(user_s *self)
{
    user_s tmp = USER_CONSTRUCTOR;
    
    *self = tmp;
}

void User_Destructor(user_s *self)
{
    // This function is currently useless and will be optimized away by gcc in this current state
    // His only purpose is to be able to add stuff in struct user (like pointer) that will need to 
    // be take care at the end (freed ?) without looking everywhere in your code.
}
```

The define will allow me to do thing like

```
int main(void)
{
    user_s user = USER_CONSTRUCTOR;
    ....
```

Now, since it seem you want to allocate your users, I add in the same way a New/Delete function :

```
user_s *User_New(void)
{
    user_s *new = NULL;
    
    if (!(new = malloc(sizeof(*new)))) {
        // TODO : printf error message
        return NULL;
    }
    User_Constructor(new);
    
    return new;
}

void User_Delete(user_s *self)
{
    if (self) {
        User_Destructor(self);
        free(self);
    }
}
```

Now, onto the main event : you want to be able to fill your user struct from 2 source : stdin and fd.

So, you simply have to do this :

```
void User_Copy(user_s *dst, const user_s *src)
{
    strcpy(dst->firstname, src->firstname);
    strcpy(dst->lastname, src->lastname);
    strcpy(dst->location, src->location);
    dst->id = src->id;
}

bool User_InitialiseFromStdin(user_s *self)
{
    // TODO : You have to check every scanf return to be sure that you have correctly read the input ! 
    // TODO : And you have to clear the buffer if there are char in it after the input, or else the next scanf will use it !
    // TODO : And don't forget to prevent buffer-overflow ! that means limitating the number of char you can put into firstname, lastname, location !

    printf("Enter first name : ");
    fflush(stdout);
    if (scanf("%15s", self->firstname) != 1) {
        return false;
    }
    printf("Enter last name : ");
    fflush(stdout);
    if (scanf("%s15", self->lastname) != 1) {
        return false;
    }
    printf("Enter location : ");
    fflush(stdout);
    if (scanf("%15s", self->location) != 1) {
        return false;
    }
    printf("Enter ID : ");
    fflush(stdout);
    if (scanf("%u", &self->id) != 1) {
        return false;
    }
    
    return true;
}

bool User_InitialiseFromFileDescriptor(user_s *self, int fd)
{
    user_s  user           = USER_CONSTRUCTOR;
    ssize_t nbBytesRead    = 0;
    bool    returnFunction = false;
    
    if ((nbBytesRead = read(fd, &user, sizeof(user))) != sizeof(user)) {
        // TODO : Error message (you can use nbBytesRead and errno to have custom message, like you did)
        goto END_FUNCTION; 
    }
    // It's dangerous here, because we don't know if all char array (firstname, lastname, location) contain an ending \0
    // TODO : Check it before copying the user struct
    User_Copy(self, &user);
    
    returnFunction = true;
    /* GOTO */END_FUNCTION:
    User_Destructor(&user);
    return returnFunction;
}
```

I hope you now see how easy to read those function are, since they are only doing one thing (the most part of the function is to check error ...).

If you want to write your struct into the fd, easy too :

```
bool User_WriteInfoFileDescriptor(const user_s *self, int fd)
{
    ssize_t nbBytesRead = 0;
    
    if ((nbBytesRead = write(fd, self, sizeof(*self))) != sizeof(*self)) {
        // TODO : Error message (you can use nbBytesRead and errno to have custom message)
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

you don't have to really do anything else. Juste be warry that firstname is a 15 letter string, and it will contain anything after the \0. So if you open your fd with a text editor, you migth see "John\0h%*$9as:rTDoe\0G!:§$=IuyaA\Miami\0Klm%%$: T" if you input "John Doe Miami".

Now, we want to see what our struct contain, so a basic Display function

```
void User_Display(const user_s *self, bool showHeader)
{
    if (showHeader) {
        printf("|First Name          | Last Name          | Location           | ID          |\n");
        printf("------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n");
    }
    printf("|%-20s|%-20s|%-20s|%-13u|\n", self->firstname, self->lastname, self->location, self->id);
    printf("------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n");
}
```

And a simple main to test is out :

```
int main(void)
{
    user_s     user1   = USER_CONSTRUCTOR;
    user_s     user2   = USER_CONSTRUCTOR;
    int        fd      = -1;
    const char *fdPath = "data.txt";
    
    printf("\n");
    User_Display(&user1, true);
    User_Display(&user2, false);
    
    User_InitialiseFromStdin(&user1);
    
    printf("\n");
    User_Display(&user1, true);
    User_Display(&user2, false);
    
    fd = open(fdPath, O_CREAT | O_WRONLY);
    User_WriteInfoFileDescriptor(&user1, fd);
    close(fd);
    
    fd = open(fdPath, O_RDONLY);
    User_InitialiseFromFileDescriptor(&user2, fd);
    close(fd);
       
    printf("\n"); 
    User_Display(&user1, true);
    User_Display(&user2, false);
    
    User_Destructor(&user1);
    User_Destructor(&user2);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Now, if you want to read X struct user from fd, I encourage you to have another struct that will represent a dynamic array of struct user, and have function that will add a user to the array, remove it, display all the user, etc etc

I hope this will be usefull ?

Comment: Nice effort, but you code is way too complex for a beginner. You will discourage him. In my opinion it would be much better to help the beginner to use simple C code without any advanced feature or concept. I will learn that later.

Comment: @fpiette By "way complex", is it about the error checking ?

Comment: @Toms It is macro use for constructor and destructor, 3 concepts he for sure has not learned yet. Better to add better error checking that those concepts. Just my opinion.

Comment: @fpiette Ah, I know what you mean then. Sure, the macro trick is confusing at first when not explained. I'm so used to use it that I have didn't tought about it. Well, if Beginner0 have question, he will ask them I suppose.